# Dynamicly adding shapes based on string in ColdFusion Report Builder or...?

Tags: string, coldfusion, reporting

I've been attempting to find / do this for a week now and I can't seem to master it.
I've pre-designed a ticketing system for live events in Illustrator and moved it to Publisher and also moved it to a PDF.

I was using ColdFusion to take HTML and make these tickets (10 per page) using CFDOCUMENT but that just wasn't allowing for the "design" elements that I really wanted.

So my last attempt is to dig out Report Builder and see what it can do...

I have a code that will show up on each ticket that is unique to that ticket.
It looks something like this:

```
GUP-Z2F G 4 C
```

The last 3 letters will have circle backgrounds for a hole punch to punch them out.
There is 1 letter / number per day of the event.
So for 3 character string it would be 3 days.

Some codes may be 6 to 10 days... who knows!

```
GUP-Z2F G 4 C P T 6
```

Attaching an Image to this message to illustrate it.
[Ticket Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsuoP.png)

Basically, my code in the query is like so:

```
fulltoken,tokenPart1,tokenPart2,tokenPart3
GUP-Z2F-G4C,GUP,Z2F,G4C
```

I would need to split the last part of the token into an array by character and then create a new circle for each letter and put the letter / number in that circle.

Would report builder work good for this? or is there another way?
I've looked into iText, Flying Saucer, cfdocument, cfpdf, etc.
None of them gave me the design freedom that I'm needing.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

**UPDATE**
I've also generated the image with cfimage stuff for the code which would work but I was hoping for something crisp and vector but if I could improve the DPI of the code image generated to maybe 100dpi it might look okay... is this possible?

Comment: I've also generated the image with cfimage stuff for the code which would work but I was hoping for something crisp and vector but if I could improve the DPI of the code image generated to maybe 100dpi it might look okay... is this possible?

Comment: improve the DPI of the code image generated? can't you start with a bigger canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can have the image show only if the param is defined.  See Print Control under Property of your shape/circle.

So you just draw all the circles background you need, add a text field on top of each them, and then set them to show only if `len(param.dayX)` or something like that?

Comment: GREAT SOLUTION! My only issue with it now is since any part of the code could increase in length it would need to expand / contract with the size changes and not be fixed to a particular position on the report.  Any ideas?

Comment: Another idea I had was using the report functions, but not sure if you can programmatically draw elipses or shapes...?

Comment: expand / contract? like... how dynamic? Could you have provided multiple report/ticket? You're going to have a ticket that prints 30 circles for a month of visit? :S

Comment: Essentially, I most likely will have a day cap like 10 days or something but ya essentially it's one character per day.

Comment: ya, can you make it semi-fixed, maybe prepare multiple CF Reports? one  for 1-10, another for 11-30, etc etc?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well this will work in CFDocument/CFPDF, but here's the approach I would try:

First, split your string.  There are a number of ways to do this, the most obvious being to loop over the string length and get the left(), mid(), and right() subsctrings as appropriate.

For each substring, add a <span> with a class that has the circle as a background element.  You would probably also want to set an appropriate width to allow for the hole punching.

Apply this HTML to the ticket in PDF.

Comment: I did this, it's just not very flexible as far as design goes.
And requires extensive knowledge of building them.